# Download File by starting a Chrome Process

Tags: c#, google-chrome, download

I want to download a file by just starting a new Process of Chrome. I've found the parameter "--download", so the solution should be "CHROMEPATH --download URI". ( http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#download )

I wrote the code to start the process in C#, and yes, I know there are other options to do this like webclient, but I don't want to implement the download per se in my code.

```
string FILEURI = "example.org/file.png";
System.Diagnostics.Process prozess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
prozess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
prozess.StartInfo.Arguments = "--download " + FILEURI;
prozess.Start();
```

This works without any problem, but just opening the link "file://FILEURI". So I can't download it without any user interaction.

Comment: What makes you think Chrome will allow you to download a file without any user interaction? That's a pretty bit security risk.

Comment: If I can do it from a Chrome plugin, why shouldn't it work in this way too..

Comment: I mean I would not mind if the user has to say yes or no, but i don't want that the user has to change the URI etc.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome always downloads to the download folder.  You could try to just get the latest download file, like this:

```
new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile),"Downloads"))
    .GetFiles()
    .OrderByDescending(f => f.CreationTime)
    .First()
```

This has risks (as outlined by DavidG) as well as the fact the user might download another file, etc.  So this is not necessarily the best way.