# Azure DevOps - During the build pipeline run, what is the path where the Agent downloads the files locally?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

We are using a Microsoft Hosted Agent to run a build pipeline for an automated test scenario for our application. What we would like to achieve is, having our automation procedure, to download a file (from a headless chrome browser), then navigate to the path where it is downloaded and open it.

How could I find the path where the files are being downloaded inside the Agent?

Comment: can you just specify the path for the download?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's an existing web application that downloads the files to a default directory - for a Windows OS it is the "C:/Users/{user}/Downloads". This is a Linux OS though and I am not aware of that default location.

Comment: well, default directory of what? if you know the directory - just use that. although, i assume it won't be available to you on the agent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick compilation of list of pre-defined variables related to paths for the build on linux and windows self hosted agents from [official doc link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

The one you are looking is `Agent.BuildDirectory` or `Pipeline.Workspace`.

#### List of predefined variables:

| Variable type | Variable | Description | Example |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Agent | Agent.BuildDirectory | The local path on the agent where all folders for a given build pipeline are created | D:\..\agent\_work\1 |
| Agent | Agent.HomeDirectory | The directory the agent is installed into | C:\agent |
| Agent | Agent.TempDirectory | A temporary folder that is cleaned after each pipeline job | D:\..\agent\_work\_temp |
| Agent | Agent.ToolsDirectory | The directory used by tasks such as Node Tool Installer and Use Python Version to switch between multiple versions of a tool | D:\..\agent\_work\_tool |
| Agent | Agent.WorkFolder | The working directory for agent | c:\agent_work |
| Build | Build.SourcesDirectory | The local path on the agent where your source code files are downloaded. | c:\agent_work\1\s |
| Build | Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory | The local path on the agent where any artifacts are copied to before being pushed to their destination. A typical way to use this folder is to publish your build artifacts with the Copy files and Publish build artifacts tasks | c:\agent_work\1\a |
| Build | Build.StagingDirectory | The local path on the agent where any artifacts are copied to before being pushed to their destination. | c:\agent_work\1\a |
| Build | Build.BinariesDirectory | The local path on the agent you can use as an output folder for compiled binaries | c:\agent_work\1\b |
| Build | Build.Repository.LocalPath | The local path on the agent where your source code files are downloaded. | c:\agent_work\1\s |
| Build | Common.TestResultsDirectory | The local path on the agent where the test results are created. | c:\agent_work\1\TestResults |
| Pipeline | Pipeline.Workspace | The Workspace directory for a particular pipeline | /home/vsts/work/1 |
| System | System.DefaultWorkingDirectory | The local path on the agent where your source code files are downloaded. | c:\agent_work\1\s |

Comment: `Pipeline.Workspace` is agent specific, what should I do if my jobs get scheduled on different agents?

Comment: As per documentation, `Pipeline.Workspace` is same as `Agent.BuildDirectory`. You may choose to plan your agent pools accordingly.

Comment: I dont think it works like it is describe in the documentation for the on-prem solutions... :(
What i experiance for pipeline: `agent 1 worker 1 job A # agent_1://C/work/1/` | `agent 2 worker 1 job B # agent_2://C/work/1/` - so it's different machine and different disc space :(

Answer (score 2):

When you install the agent, you specify the work directory. In pipeline tasks, you can find out exactly where within that directory files are staged with variables like $(Agent.BuildDirectory). This might not be the exact location you need, but I think it is in the right direction.

For a complete list of predefined variables, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: After a few years of using ADO/VSTS/TFS - it's definitely a best practice to choose a predefined variable like $(Agent.BuildDirectory) or $(Agent.SourceDirectory) to orient your scripts from. It makes life much easier off the bat, and I've _not_ done this in the past and had an agent pool update break my script because locations changed - these variables will move with the update though.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [this document](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95759?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en-GB):

[image]

So for Linux its default location `/home/<username>/Downloads`.

I do the test in `Microsoft hosted agent-window2019` with test C# code(Hint from [Daniel!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37668473/download-file-by-starting-a-chrome-process)) like:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string FILEURI = "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Cauldron.Newton/2.0.0";
            System.Diagnostics.Process prozess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            prozess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
            prozess.StartInfo.Arguments = "--download " + FILEURI;
            prozess.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Test starts.");
        }
```

And then I use command like `dir c:\users\VssAdministrator\cauldron.newton.2.0.0.nupkg /s /b` to find the location of downloaded file: `cauldron.newton.2.0.0.nupkg`.

Then i confirmed the default download location of Chrome is still `C:/Users/{user}/Downloads`, same as using self-agent or downloading locally. (VssAdministrator is user when run windows hosted agent)

[image]

So I think Linux hosted agent should have similar behavior. You can try to find your file from `/home/<username>/Downloads` folder. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer partly through this question, and one I asked which was asking exactly the same thing, but for me, it was:
C:\Users\VssAdministrator\Downloads