# What is the meaning of the last letter "a", "b", or "s" in Azure DevOps' C:\agent\_work\1\a? Anyone know what that last letter stands for?

Tags: azure, directory, devops, pool, agent

What is the meaning of the last letter "a", "b", or "s" in Azure DevOps' directory structure:

C:\agent_work\1\a
C:\agent_work\1\b
C:\agent_work\1\s

Anyone know what that last letter stands for?

Extra credit: what's the "1" represent too?

Comment: Always assumed it was just a random folder name that’s auto created to store build assets and artifacts.

Comment: Please check: [Azure DevOps - During the build pipeline run, what is the path where the Agent downloads the files locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70972296/1176573)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Check out the [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml):

\a likely stands for "artifacts"

> **Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory** - The local path on the agent where any artifacts are copied to before being pushed to their destination. For example: `c:\agent_work\1\a`

\b likely stands for "binaries"

> **Build.BinariesDirectory** - The local path on the agent you can use as an output folder for compiled binaries.  For example: `c:\agent_work\1\b.`

\s likely stands for "sources"

> **Build.Repository.LocalPath** - The local path on the agent where your source code files are downloaded. For example: `c:\agent_work\1\s`.  This variable is synonymous with Build.SourcesDirectory.

On Hosted build agents "1" seems to be static, on a self hosted agent I have noticed this number is unique per pipeline.

Comment: I suspect Microsoft made the directory names as short as possible so they would avoid the 256 character path+filename limit that exists on some of their operating system platforms.  Nevertheless, knowing what "a", "b", and "s" stand for really helps my understanding of what files I should be expecting where.  Thanks so much, Simon!